# p:layout mixed up on page load

Tags: css, jsf, layout, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 with Mojarra 2.2.7.
On my project I have this page with `<p:layout>` and two `<p:layoutUnit>` which have a weird behavior with the scroll panels.
When the page load, it looks like this:

[image: Not desired behavior]

If you see the arrows the right layout unit is like overlapping the left one, plus there's an extra scrollbar which scrolls both `<p:layoutUnit>` which makes me think that somehow they're merged into one when the page load.
When I "move" the components, somehow, like zooming in or zooming out, the both `<p:layoutUnit>` separate, making my desired behavior. If you see on the top arrow, there's a new scrollbar for the left `<p:layoutUnit>` and the right scroll on the first image dissapear.

[image: Desired behavior]

My code for that page looks like this:

```
        <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:1000px;" styleClass="backgroundless">
            <p:layoutUnit position="center" size="620" >
                <p:tabView id="tabView">   
                    <c:forEach items="#{tareaController.mfuncionesAsociadas}" var="mFuncion" varStatus="loop1">
                        <p:tab id="t_funcion_#{loop1.index}" title="#{mFuncion.nombre}"  >
                            <f:subview id="tab_#{loop1.index}">
                                <p:panelGrid id="pg_funcion_#{loop1.index}">
                                    <ui:include src="#{mFuncion.paginaFuncion}"></ui:include>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </f:subview>
                        </p:tab>
                    </c:forEach>
                </p:tabView>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="east" rendered="#{tareaController.tieneVisor eq true}" size="620">
                <p:panelGrid id="v_doc" style="width: 100%; top: 50px;">
                    <p:row>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
```

I'd like to now why is that behavior, maybe because the ui:include loads the page pre-rendering and I'd have to somehow update the `<p:layout>` status post-load? If that's it I have no idea how to get that done.
Thanks a lot beforehand.

**EDIT :**  I changed the min width and the min height to a higher value and since they aren't close enough I don't get the third weird scrollbar so I though it could be something related to the overflow style, but I changed it and nothing happens. 
Finally, I give up with this, I just reduced the min size of the layout and they don't overlap.